# How to RESOLVE PARTITION RANGE ALL in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, indexing, partitioning

I have a query below which uses in the execution plan a PARTITION RANGE ALL. However the table is PARTITIONED and I have an index on column "comar".

1. What is the root cause?
2. How can I optimize it to get a PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR?

Query:

```
select * from CFTDAT_TT D,  IHSPOS L  where L.COMAR=D.COMAR ;
```

index:

```
CREATE  INDEX "OPS$BRU"."IHSPOS3" ON "OPS$BRU"."IHSPOS" ("COMAR") ;
```

Here is a screenshot of the execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Do you want to force PARTITION RANGE as in the question title? From the question details it seems you want to make it use your index, which has nothing to do with partitioning. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: 1. Partition range iterator will not appear unless you provide some filter for partitioning columns. 2. Index will not be used in every case, its usage depends on how much IO optimizer **expects** to do in case of index scan and table scan. Your question doesn't have any information about table sizes in terms of # of rows and how much rows should be retrieved from the big table. That's why we cannot guess why optimized decided to use this execution plan

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question :) .About the index just I want to provide the maximum of information to help me resolve this problem ,the table IHSPOS contains 2389 ROWS and CFTDAT_TT it's temporary table and it contains3 rows

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are generally most effective for finding a small number of rows in a large table, but in this case you want every row of IHSPOS.

You can hint it to use your index with `select /*+ index(l) */` but it looks as though this would need to read more data and result in slower execution.

Comment: thank you for your help .I added hint but the same issue